# Use external USB 3.0 SSD with 2012 iMac for the OS?

Tags: macos, imac, usb, ssd

So it is possible that I can get a good deal on a 2012 iMac. The only thing that scares me is the slow 1tb hard drive in it. I searched on how to replace it but it is extremely complicated because the iMac is glued together, I'm not ready to go down that road.

So my idea was to take a **SATA3 SSD**, put it in a **SATA USB 3.0 HDD enclosure** and then connect that over USB 3.0 and install MacOS on it.

**Q: Is it a good idea to run your OS on an external hard drive?** Does anyone have experience with this or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's **totally fine** to install and run macOS on an external HDD/SSD.

Especially since USB 3 you can get the same speed as the internal drive – or even **faster** in the case of an SSD.

The only **downside** is the fact that you will have one **USB-port permanently occupied**. It may also not be as pleasing to one's eye if there's an external drive permanently attached.

Enjoy your new iMac!

Comment: Thanks! I dont really care about one usb being blocked, I'm probably going to use a usb hub anyway, and a permanently attached drive doesnt bother me. If it does I will tape it to the back of the iMac or something.

Comment: would Thunderbolt be a better option for this set-up?

Comment: Thunderbolt WOULD be faster but Thunderbolt enclosures are difficult to find and rather expensive. I ended up doing just this but with Firewire 800 as my USB ports are only USB 2. It is faster.

Comment: @Tanonic great. There are also some kind of iMac "backpacks" available. It's a piece of metal that you can attach to the back of your iMac which provides a place for your SSD/HDD.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy if USB 3.0 is the bottleneck then yes, go for a thunderbolt drive. I use a TB RAID for really storage. For everything else I use USB 3 drives.

Comment: I know thunderbolt would be a lot faster but to my surprise I couldn't find any sata enclosures for thunderbolt 2 which I find really weird because thunderbolt would be perfect for fast disks. I also use firewire on my macbook pro and Desktop PC, but the iMac 2012 doesnt have any firewire ports so I didn't see it as an option. I could use a thunderbolt 2 -> firewire adapter and then use a firewire enclosure I guess, but that seems overly complicated.

Comment: USB 3 Supports 5000 MBit/s, FW800 800 MBit/s and USB 2 480 MBit/s. Go for USB 3.

Comment: Oh I somehow thought firewire had higher bandwidth then usb 3. I will definately go for usb 3, thanks

Comment: "*Especially since USB 3 you can get the same speed as the internal drive – or even faster in the case of an SSD.*" – Do you have a source for this? I wouldn't be surprised if the USB interface slows down random access considerably.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but the 2012 iMac uses i5 which has a SATA w/ 3Gbps link speed and 1.5Gbps negotiated link speed, like this one: http://tidbits.com/resources/2012-07/ssd_system_info.png

Answer (score 0):

21" 2012 imac could be bought with i7. Excellent machine, boosted to 20 gb RAM

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP665?locale=en_US

Comment: The spec said the RAM could only be 16gb max, but appears to have headroom to run it.

Comment: I think the iMac I was offered only has an i5 but I think that is enough for me, I don't need an i7. And for the ram I don't know how much it has but I think since the standard is 8gb, that it is 8gb. 8gb was always enough for me in my desktop and my MBP but another ram stick really isn't expensive so I might upgrade to 16gb